# Change dynamically type of the Model in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the type of my Model, from ObjectType1 to ObjectType2, when I call the View. I am using MVC 4. Can somebody tell me if this is possible at all and if yes, how?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Master1.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Path.Path.Path.ObjectType1>" %>
```

Scenario:
I have an Action that sends an ObjectType1 to a strongly-typed View. Also I send another ObjectType2 in TempData. In the View I display information from the first Model and the Second Model. But I want to edit and submit ObjectType1. Now I have second View, in which I'm doing the other way around. The problem is that I have two Views with almost the same code and I have to reload the page if I want to swith from one to another. I submit the object with Post method, if it matters.

Comment: If you're trying to do this, then you're doing it wrong. Write your scenario and I'm sure someone will provide a better solution.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem that is not one of the existing answers you should post your solution as an answer, not edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a view is bound to one model.

If you can explain your actual problem, then perhaps better suggestions can be made, for example changing the logic that requires you to use the same view for different models. Perhaps it can be solved using DisplayTemplates. You might even use a `dynamic` model if you don't care about strong-typedness, maintainability and reusability.

Answer (score 0):

If you have similar property name and type, then try with `dynamic` type

***ASPX syntax***

```
  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"

<% if (Model!=null) { 
     //render the value from model
}%>
```

***Razor***

```
@model dynamic

@if(Model!=null)
{
   <p> @Model.Name </p>
}
```

In Controller action

```
var model = new  Employee{ Name = "MM", Salary= 2800 };
return this.View(model);
```

Comment: But what is happening when I want to submit the Model to the Controller?

Comment: @user2831001, its not a problem. Model binder will take care of wiring :)

Comment: But it gives me a problem when I use lambda expressions in the Model."An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operations". <%: html.HiddenFor(m=>m.id)%>

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I would create 2 strongly typed views and return whichever one is required for the scenario.

You can always use partial views for the common ui between the 2 views.

That way each view can have a form which posts back to separate controller actions, each one accepting a different model.

Comment: Okay, but can you give me an example please.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a view is bound to one model. but in case you are curious about that? then you can do by using this simple trick. I apply this trick several times and it worked for me.

- From your Action Method.
- You have to return a dynamic value type from
  Action method.
- For Example:
- In first Case: you have to return List
- In second Case: you have to return List

So you can write code something list this:

**Action Method**

```
public ActionResult foo(int? productId = null, int? customerId = null)
{
    // if ProductId has Value:
    if(productId != null)
    {
        Viewbag.ModelType = "Product";
        //... Logic
        return View((dynamic)(productsList))
    }

    // if CustomerId has Value:
    if(CustomerId != null)
    {
        Viewbag.ModelType = "Customer";
        //... Logic
        return View((dynamic)(CustomerList))
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable(dynamic)
//...

if(Viewbag.ModelType == "Customer")
{ // do this.. }

if(Viewbag.ModelType == "Product")
{ // do this.. }

etc...
```

I hope you get the idea...